# Adjust function to work with dplyr/magrittr

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr, nse

I have:

```
df <- data_frame(
  a = 1:2, 
  b = list(1:10, 4:40)
)
```

and

```
foo <- function(x) mean(unlist(x))
```

The following works as expected:

```
df$b %>% foo
```

However, I was not able to figure out which modifications of `foo` are needed in order for `df %>% foo(b)` to work.

Comment: This is really about dplyr only, not about magrittr: the same issue arises when calling the function as `foo(df, b)`.

Comment: @Sotos That won’t work with non-standard evaluation or other arguments, so while it’s possible I don’t recommend it because it doesn’t follow the reset of the dplyr API.

Comment: If you want a data.frame back as normal for dplyr, `foo <- function(.tbl, ...){summarise_at(.tbl, vars(...), funs(mean(unlist(.))))}` works without diving into the lazyeval NSE tools. Wrapping `summarise_at` in `unlist` would give you a vector instead of a data.frame. FYI, the SE/NSE system has just been rebuilt in the development version, though (all the `*_` functions are now deprecated), but I haven't seen docs for it yet.

Comment: you can update the function to be something like `foo <- function(df, x) {
 x <- df[ deparse(substitute(x))]
 mean(unlist(x))
 }`

Comment: @Lucy You should write that up as an answer, as it's the correct base R way to do it for one variable. Extending it to more would be a great answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass an `...` parameter directly to the `vars` helper of `summarise_at`, e.g.

```
foo <- function(.tbl, ...){
    summarise_at(.tbl, 
                 vars(...), 
                 funs(mean(unlist(.))))
}
```

It works for single variables, list column or not:

```
df %>% foo(b)
## # A tibble: 1 × 1
##          b
##      <dbl>
## 1 18.48936
```

or multiple:

```
df %>% foo(a, b)
## # A tibble: 1 × 2
##       a        b
##   <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1   1.5 18.48936
```

To go further with NSE, check out [lazyeval](https://github.com/hadley/lazyeval), which is the package dplyr uses to implement its NSE.

Also note that the SE/NSE system of dplyr has just been rebuilt in the development version (not on CRAN yet, and not yet documented).

---

Bonus points: Do it all in base R!

```
foo <- function(.tbl, ...){
    # collect dots as character vector
    cols <- as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1])
    cls <- class(.tbl)

    # handle grouped tibbles properly
    if('grouped_df' %in% cls){
        cls <- cls[which(cls != 'grouped_df')]    # drop grouping
        res <- aggregate(.tbl[cols], 
                         .tbl[attr(.tbl, 'vars')], 
                         FUN = function(x){mean(unlist(x))})
    } else {
        res <- as.data.frame(lapply(.tbl[cols], function(x){mean(unlist(x))}))
    }

    class(res) <- cls    # keep class (tibble, etc.)
    res
}
```

which works with list columns, groups, and multiple columns or groups, keeping class but dropping grouping:

```
df %>% foo(a, b)
## # A tibble: 1 × 2
##       a        b
##   <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1   1.5 18.48936

df %>% group_by(a) %>% foo(b)
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##       a     b
##   <int> <dbl>
## 1     1   5.5
## 2     2  22.0

mtcars %>% foo(mpg, hp)
##        mpg       hp
## 1 20.09062 146.6875

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% foo(hp, mpg)
## # A tibble: 6 × 4
##     cyl    am        hp      mpg
##   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1     4     0  84.66667 22.90000
## 2     6     0 115.25000 19.12500
## 3     8     0 194.16667 15.05000
## 4     4     1  81.87500 28.07500
## 5     6     1 131.66667 20.56667
## 6     8     1 299.50000 15.40000
```

Comment: About the doc: [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/nse.Rmd) they say: see `vignette("programming")` but I can't seem to find it. They're apparently migrating from `lazyeval` to `rlang` but `rlang` has no vignette yet. We'll know more soon I guess

Comment: I'm impatient, but I guess I can wait a little longer if it means getting rid of `.dots` 

Answer (score 4):

You could get to the result this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    mutate_(mn=~map_dbl(b, mean), size=~map_dbl(b, length)) %>%
    summarize_(m=~weighted.mean(mn, size))
#  m
#   <dbl>
# 1 18.49
```

Or define `foo` in this way:

```
foo2 <- function(d, col) {
    col_name <- as.character(substitute(col))
    mean(unlist(d[[col_name]]))
}
df %>% foo2(b)
[1] 18.49
```

Answer (score 4):

you can update the function with something like:

```
foo <- function(df, x) {
  x <- df[ deparse(substitute(x))] 
  mean(unlist(x)) }

df %>% foo(b)
[1] 18.48936
```